# Keyboard shortcut to trigger element command menu in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In the Chrome DevTools "Elements" panel, I would like a keyboard shortcut to bring up the command menu that a right-click brings up:

[image]

So: If I've already selected the element (which I can do via arrow navigation, that's great), bring up that menu via a keyboard shortcut.

Alternately, the menu element I'm trying to access is "Store as global variable", so a keyboard shortcut for that individual action would do as well.

Thanks!

Comment: FWIW in Windows there's a standard key "Apps" or Shift-F10. In MacOS it's different, see [How do I open the context menu from a Mac keyboard?](//apple.stackexchange.com/q/32715)